# Regex - Check if expression ends with a newline

Tags: regex, search, newline

I'm using the expression [A-F]{4} to try and check through the dictionary file on unix called "words". Problem is that right now it checks all characters to find a four letter combination of A-F (Which mean I can get part of a word that matches the expression) where I need it to only find words thats matchs this. I would check for spaces after the expression, but the problem is that every word is on a new line and does not contain spaces after it.

So is there a way I can check if their is a line break after the combination I seek with the regular expression just like you can with spaces?

I'm writing my code in java if the new line possibility isn't there and anyone knows a smart trick.

The code with \b added to the expression: http://pastebin.com/kYqr6Ex6

Comment: What is an example string (or paragraph) that you are trying to match?

Comment: Out of these (Don't really know how to format it, so here it is on pastebin too: http://pastebin.com/CtQvSWAF):
beechnut's
beechnuts
beef
beef's
beefburger

It needs to match "beef" and none of the other words. (As the words are longer than 4 characters. Right now (without \b) it beec twice as part of the two first words and beef three times (one time with beef and two times as part of the two other words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex (using borders): `\b[A-F]{4}\b`

Example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-F]{4}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ABCD BCDE GHT GHJL\n" +
                                    "XSE EFAB BHUI ABCE\n");
// check all occurance
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ABCD
BCDE
EFAB
ABCE
```

Link to Fiddler:
http://rubular.com/r/lvpbG4nAYG

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work :/ (Doesn't find any matches compared to before where it found all matches in the file) 
Can I check if the newline contains the borders somehow?

Here's the code btw: http://pastebin.com/kYqr6Ex6 
I have added it to the post too.

Comment: this is the right idea, but it isn't a java question, it's linux command line question, so don't double (ie escape) the backslashes

Comment: It works! I needed the double slashs (Sorry, i'm still new to regex)

Thanks for both the suggestion with \b and the example!

Comment: @Bohemian he says in the question he uses Java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every desired word starts and ends with whitespace(includes tabs and newlines), you could use this regex:

### Regex

`[A-F]{4}(?!\S)`

### Example

[Regex101 Permalink](http://regex101.com/r/uU8gF5)

Answer (score 0):

For *nix command line tools, the word boundary regexes are `\<` and `\>` for start/end of words, so try this regex:

```
[A-F]{4}\>
```

If you're seeking a whole word, rather than just the end of a word, add the word start regex:

```
\<[A-F]{4}\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the flag `Pattern.MULTILINE` on Pattern and use the regex `\b[A-F]{4}\b$`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-F]{4}$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

When the `Pattern.MULTILINE` is active, the $ will match with break-line.

Used [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test and I think it's giving the result you want.